# Reference to part of filename recalculates to wrong workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula:
`=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND(".xls",CELL("filename"))-4;4)`

It looks for the last 4 characters in the filename.
This works correctly, however when I open another workbook, or do a modification in a different workbook and return to this workbook it changed it's calculation result to the last 4 characters of the last used workbook, prior to activating this workbook.
Is there a way (avoiding vba and not messing with calculation to manual) to prevent this?

Comment: do a loop for the actions on workbook 1 then a second loop for actions needed on workbook 2.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by loop, but the file with the formula is a file I have open and I need to switch from this file to different workbooks to do calculations and then get back to this workbook to select the next workbook to work in, etc. I know I can easily fix it by vba (when opening the workbook write away the calculation as value), but I wondered if it's possible by formula.

Comment: I use a similar formula (MID(@CELL("filename",K1),FIND("T ",@CELL("filename",K3))+2,2)*1) in several of my workbooks and it does not get confused when I switch... and often have 6, 8 or 12 books open at once. Must be something else you are doing.

Comment: Does it not change the value if you press F9 in one of the other workbooks and you return to the workbook? With me it then shows the last 4 characters from the previous file. On F9 it returns to the correct value.